# Rearrange int value from MMDDYYY to YYYYMMDD using MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

I have a VARCHAR data type in field name date:

```
DATE

09282016
09272016
```

I want to arrange it to:

```
DATE
20160928
20160927
```

How can I do that in MySQL?

Comment: how do you manage the first zero (leading zero), if your field is integer. and do you store 2 digits for months from 1 through 9 ?

Comment: sorry data type is varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of `STR_TO_DATE` and `DATE_FORMAT` function you can achieve this.

**Select Query:**

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(your_date_column,'%m%d%Y'),'%Y%m%d')
FROM your_table;
```

**Update Query:**

```
UPDATE 
your_table 
SET your_date_column = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(your_date_column,'%m%d%Y'),'%Y%m%d');
```

---

**Demonstration:**

```
SET @str := '09282016';

SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(@str,'%m%d%Y'),'%Y%m%d') AS output;
```

---

```
Output
20160928
```

**Date should be stored in `date` datatype.**

Comment: i did this before I ask question. the only problem is the y in '%m%d%Y' is small letter. thank you